# Accessing Prometheus Monitoring Values through Rancher

Tags: prometheus, rancher

I have a rancher cluster with monitoring enabled, from my understanding this enables prometheus monitoring and exposes extra values from it.

For example: after enabling monitoring, the dashboard shows usage values in green. (Before only the reserved value was shown).
[image]
I can access the reserved values from the rancher api, using the /nodes endpoint, but I can't get the values in green.

Can I get this using the rancher API?
If not, how can I access these metrics?

Thank You